# Validar formulario HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validación

¿Por qué motivo me deja enviar datos si los campos están vacíos? Debería salirme la alerta y no dejarme seguir.

```js
function validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente(){
  var idemail, password1;
  idemail = document.getElementById("email").value;
  password1 = document.getElementById("password").value;

  if(idemail=="" || password1==""){
    alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios.");
    return false;
  }else if(idemail.length>50){
    alert("El email debe tener menos de 51 carácteres.");
    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    document.getElementById("email").focus();
    return false;
  }else if(password1.length>16){
    alert("La contraseña debe tener menos de 17 carácteres.");
    document.getElementById("password").focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario de Login - Cliente</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_iniciar_sesion.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="logueo_cliente.php" method="POST" class="form" onsubmit="return validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente();">
      <h2>INICIAR SESIÓN</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="email">
      <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="password">
      <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"><br/>
        <p class="form-link">¿Aún no tienes una cuenta? <a href="registrar.php">Regístrate aquí</a></p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

En la consola aparece el error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Ponle el id a los campos email y password, recoges los valores en javascript por un id que no has declarado, sólo has puesto la propiedad 'name'.

Comment: Estás capturando el valor de los elementos por su id: `getElementById`... pero resulta que en el HTML los elementos **no tienen id**. Si quieres recuperar los valores así, debes otorgar el id a cada elemento. Ejemplo: **`<input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="email" id="email">`** o bien, puedes cambiar el name por el id, depende de lo que harás luego: `<input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" id="email">`... lo mismo con el input de password.

Comment: Acabo de incluir ese valor en los input y tampoco me funciona.

Comment: Pues me sigue permitiendo avanzar de página aún sin cargar valores en los campos.

Comment: Cierto. Era problema de caché, la borré y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Claro, ahora la publico

Comment: Pues el codigo que tu pones, si no rellenas alguno de los campos sale la alerta.

Comment: @Mariano el usuario ha cambiado el código corrigiendolo y colocando las id si no m equivoco no? Deberian volver atras las correcciones?

Comment: @GDP Seguía sin funcionarme después del cambio por eso edité la pregunta con las "id". Se solucionó al borrar la caché del navegador.

Comment: @omaza1990 si si, tranqui. El cache juega malas pasadas. Refresca con control+f5 en lugar de normal. Yo lo comentaba porque no tendria mucho sentido la respuesta con la pregunta ya funcional :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta definir la propiedad `id` en los inputs `email` y `password`, ya que es la que utilizas en `javascript` para recoger los valores y comprobar si están vacíos. Al no estar definidos no puede recoger el valor.

**Código HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Formulario de Login - Cliente</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_iniciar_sesion.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="logueo_cliente.php" method="POST" class="form" onsubmit="return validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente();">
            <h2>INICIAR SESIÓN</h2>
            <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="email" id="email">
            <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="password" id="password">
            <div align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"><br/>
                <p class="form-link">¿Aún no tienes una cuenta? <a href="registrar.php">Regístrate aquí</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: me ha ayudado a entender como funciona. Nueva en esto